# Routing in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony1, url-routing

I have two links:

```
http://www.mypage.com/phone/show/id/1
```

and:

```
http://www.mypage.com/phone/show/id/2
```

I would like makes links for this

```
http://www.mypage.com/linksone
```

and

```
http://www.mypage.com/linkstwo
```

Is it possible to do that with Symfony routing system?

```
linksone:
  url: /linksone
  param: { module: phone, action: show}

linkstwo:
  url: /linkstwo
  param: { module: phone, action: show}
```

Where I can add ID?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this should do it:

```
linksone:
  url: /linksone
  param: { module: phone, action: show, id: 1}

linkstwo:
  url: /linkstwo
  param: { module: phone, action: show, id: 2}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this in Symfony 2+ you need to do the following routing, hopefully someone will find this useful. This is just an example and not using your names/routes.

```
home_route:
   path: /home
   defaults: { _controller: DemoCoreBundle:StaticPageController:home }

about_route:
   path: /about
   defaults: { _controller: DemoCoreBundle:StaticPageController:about }

team_route:
   path: /team/{member_id}
   defaults: { _controller: DemoCoreBundle:StaticPageController:team, member_id:null }
   requirements:
       member_id: \d+
```